# ReactNavigation useRouter params dont get my param

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i have this errors
'route' is possibly 'undefined'.
Property 'figureID' does not exist on type 'object'

and im using this:

```
  const route = useRoute().params;
  console.log(route.figureID);
```

but my figureID always undefined, i have this global on my type folder:

```
export declare global {
  namespace ReactNavigation {
    interface RootParamList {
      home: underfined;
      productDetails: {
        params: {
          figureID: number;
        };
      };
    }
  }
}
```

but if i do

```
  const route = useRoute<any>().params;
  console.log(route.figureID);
```

it works, but i don't need an any in my code, anyone know how to solve this insue?

and i call a funcion to seend the param to that page:

```
  const navigate = (figureID: number) => {
    navigation.navigate("productDetails", {
      params: { figureID },
    });
  };
```